# Update existing row mysql linq

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have html page with table. When I change field I need to re-save existing record in table.

```
public int SaveTask(TimesheetListModel task, int userId)
{
    var worklog = new tblWorkLog();

    if (task != null)
    {
        worklog.AccountId = userId;     
        worklog.WorkDate = task.Date;
        worklog.Note = task.Note;       
        worklog.TaskTitle = task.Task;

        DataContext.tblWorkLogs.InsertOnSubmit(worklog);

        DataContext.SubmitChanges(ConflictMode.FailOnFirstConflict);
    }

    return worklog.WorkItemId;
}
```

This function saves data to table `tblWorklogs` and returns me id of record. But when I updating record, I already have id of record and I need to find this record in table and update fields. How to do this? I wrote begin function:

```
public bool UpdateTask(TimesheetListModel task)
{
    /* If update succefull must return true */
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not too sure on your implementation but depending on the context you could do something like.

```
public bool UpdateTask(TimesheetListModel task)
{
    var entity = DataContext.tblWorkLogs.FirstOrDefault(twl => twl.Id == task.Id);
    if (entity != null)
    {
      entity.AccountId = userId;     
      entity.WorkDate = task.Date;
      entity.Note = task.Note;       
      entity.TaskTitle = task.Task;
      DataContext.SubmitChanges();
      return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

The logic behind it is:

- Attempt to retrieve entity from Database.
- If it exists, edit property/properties as desired
- Save Changes

This all relies on whether you are tracking entities, otherwise you have to `Attach` the entity.